# Search and compare input string from .Net Core app to multiple SQL columns

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-core

I'm sorry if the way I asked the question is confusing. I have a .Net Core E-commerce project that sells music albums. I want to add a search bar so that the user can search for albums by title, artist or genre. Those are stored in a SQL db. I can't seem to find a way to compare the string that the user inputs to all three of those, only one. Here's what I have:

```
public ViewResult Search(string searchString)
        {
            string _searchString = searchString;
            IEnumerable<Album> albums;


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_searchString))
            {
                albums = _albumRepository.Albums.OrderBy(p => p.AlbumId);
            }
            else 
            {
                albums = _albumRepository.Albums.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(_searchString.ToLower()));

            }

            return View("~/Views/Album/List.cshtml", new AlbumListViewModel { Albums = albums});
        }
```

Comment: Look into [full-text search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017). These queries will not perform if you have a significant amount of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little difficult to answer, given that we have no visibility into your actual model(s) here, but generally speaking, you just need to use the logical OR operator:

```
albums = _albumRepository.Albums.Where(p =>
    p.Name.ToLower().Contains(_searchString.ToLower()) ||
    p.Artist.ToLower().Contains(_searchString.ToLower()) ||
    p.Genre.ToLower().Contains(_searchString.ToLower())
);
```

If `Artist`/`Genre` are actually reference props, you'd just drill into them, i.e. `p.Artist.Name.ToLower().Contains(...)`, etc.

Comment: exactly what I needed, I tried so manu things but never thought to try something so simple

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of conditions, you can move the code to a method, to improve readability/re-use:

```
albums = _albumRepository.Albums.Where(p => p.Match(searchString))
```

Then create the extension method for type `p` (`Albums` class) or just add this on the class itself if it makes more sense to be there in your project.

```
public static class AlbumsExtensions
{
    public static bool Match(this Album album, string search)
    {

        // whatever complex logic you have stays here

        var search = searchString.ToLower();

        var result = p.Name.ToLower().Contains(search) ||
                     p.Artist.ToLower().Contains(search) ||
                     p.Genre.ToLower().Contains(search);

        return result ;
    }
}
```

Last but not least, note that string compare is not trivial if you support unicode and several languages.

For more ingormation, take a look at (for example):
 [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)